# How to do async callbacks with state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to search for this, but all I got were doing promises etc with hooks which is not exactly the question I'm trying to ask.

A common pattern for redux-thunk is `getState`, that way you inspect state after a promise has resolved incase of race conditions etc
However all react hooks are designed to be immutable, and therefore the state we get is at the time of creation, not after possible setState calls after fetches have started.

```js
const useMyHook = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({a: null, result: null});
  const func = () => {
    const initialState = state.a
    someFetch(state.a).then(result => {
      // Obviously this line is wrong and just for show, normally I could `getState`
      if (state.a === initialState) {
        setState({...state, result})
      }
    })
  }
  return {func, setState};
}
```

So my concern here is that when we do some `setState` after the fetch has started, when the fetch finishes, then some old state will be rewritten or something?

My guess is that calling an old setState like this causes a "rewind" where the state rewinds to the old state, then all the new state applications are done on top, but I'm just speculating.

Certainly when I try this type of code, as I'm rendering the result, I see a "flash" with the old result, which then disappears. I am currently using a ref to get around this, but I don't think I can do that in all cases.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are trying to preserve the previous state and combine it with the result from the promise ?

Comment: I'm trying to use the latest "state" to determine what to do when my promise resolves, there's lots of possibilities, which includes combining if desired. For example, I return setState from this hook function, so another part of the code could update the state here

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the previous state and check what you need to check there(see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) for reference):

```
setState((prev) => {
  ...
})
```

Or you could use `useReducer` and handle all of the changes and decisions for those changes in a reducer. See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, setState callback doesn't work across multiple states, and useReducer doesn't work within the component, for example checking if you're in the correct "mode" and haven't navigated etc. I assume it works if you do state checks within the reducer itself. Thunk patterns with hooks exist, but they don't carry over if you want to use multiple reducers for example. Probably not the worst, but https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-thunk-reducer or similar might be a good middle ground